# How can I plot "pandas.core.series.Series“ in Bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, graph, bokeh

I want to plot the variable `tmp` using Bokeh.
`tmp` has timestamp index (e.g. 2011-01-29) and integer（e.g. 1000）.

`tmp` is "pandas.core.series.Series".

```
output_notebook()

p = figure(title='title', 
           x_axis_type='datetime',  
           x_axis_label='timestamp', 
           y_axis_label='quantity',
           width=800,height=350
          )
p.line(x=tmp.index, y=tmp.values)
show(p)
```

This code gives me an empty plot.

The Below script is making sample data.

```
import pandas

origin_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10004],
    "B":[20000, 20001, 20002, 20003, 20004]

},
index = ["2011-01-29", "2011-01-30", "2011-01-31", "2011-02-01", "2011-02-02"])

tmp = tmp.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Please provide the actual data so that the example code can be run.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The sample data is added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data, the index has string type - you have never told it that it's a timestamp.

Add this:

```py
origin_data.index = pd.to_datetime(origin_data.index)
```